# How to merge two dataframes the smartest way?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry about title, not sure how to word the question.

I have two dataframes. One with dates and orders (stocks):

```
    Date_buy    Name_buy    
0   2004-01-30  TLT
1   2004-02-02  TLT 
2   2004-02-03  TLT
3   2004-02-04  TLT
4   2004-02-05  TLT
... ... ... ... ... ...
4224    2020-08-26  TLT
4225    2020-08-27  TLT
4226    2020-08-28  TLT 
4227    2020-08-31  TLT
4228    2020-09-01  VO
```

And another dataframe with prices for the stocks:

```
         Date   VO          TLT
927 2004-01-30  49.349998   87.040001
928 2004-02-02  49.709999   86.500000
929 2004-02-03  49.509998   86.940002
930 2004-02-04  48.959999   86.769997
931 2004-02-05  49.090000   86.430000
... ... ... ...
5386    2021-07-27  238.509995  149.639999
5387    2021-07-28  239.559998  149.649994
5388    2021-07-29  241.259995  148.820007
5389    2021-07-30  240.470001  149.520004
5390    2021-08-02  240.690002  150.369995
```

How can I merge / join these two dataframes in the smartest way to get following:

```
     Date_buy   Name_buy Price
0   2004-01-30  TLT     87.040001
1   2004-02-02  TLT     86.500000
2   2004-02-03  TLT     86.940002
3   2004-02-04  TLT     86.769997
4   2004-02-05  TLT     86.430000
... ... ... ... ... ...
4224    2020-08-26  TLT 164.029999
4225    2020-08-27  TLT 161.240005
4226    2020-08-28  TLT 161.119995
4227    2020-08-31  TLT 162.190002
4228    2020-09-01  VO  182.089996
```

For the given date the price for the stock on that date is merged/joined.

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward inner join.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Not a straightforward inner join because df2 needs to be transformed to long form @Prune since one of the key values are columns.

Comment: That answer, pd.concat([orders, VO_TLT], join='inner'), gives me nothing. Literally leaves an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) `df2` to long form, and rename the columns to match `df1` then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
merged = df1.merge(
    df2.melt('Date', var_name='Name_buy').rename(columns={'Date': 'Date_buy'})
)
```

```
     Date_buy Name_buy      value
0  2004-01-30      TLT  87.040001
1  2004-02-02      TLT  86.500000
2  2004-02-03      TLT  86.940002
3  2004-02-04       VO  48.959999
```

(Slightly modified df1 and df2 to get the join behaviour shown in a smaller set)

[`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), of course, works as well:

```
merged = df1.merge(
    df2.set_index('Date').stack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_1': 'Name_buy', 'Date': 'Date_buy'})
)
```

`merged`:

```
     Date_buy Name_buy          0
0  2004-01-30      TLT  87.040001
1  2004-02-02      TLT  86.500000
2  2004-02-03      TLT  86.940002
3  2004-02-04       VO  48.959999
```

---

DataFrames used:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date_buy': ['2004-01-30', '2004-02-02', '2004-02-03',
                 '2004-02-04', '2004-02-05'],
    'Name_buy': ['TLT', 'TLT', 'TLT', 'VO', 'VO']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2004-01-30', '2004-02-02', '2004-02-03', '2004-02-04'],
    'VO': [49.349998, 49.709999, 49.509998, 48.959999],
    'TLT': [87.040001, 86.5, 86.940002, 86.769997]
})
```

Comment: Upvoted due to `df.stack` inclusion. I always thought `melt` a bit magical